# Text covered by tabular

Tags: tables, multirow

Hi guys and thanks in advance for the help!

I have a problem writing my thesis with LaTeX and on internet I can't find a way to fix it.

the LaTeX text is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
The diversity of feedstocks which can be processed by pyrolysis and the large number of design variables make it difficult to identify the optimum pyrolysis technology for a given situation.

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
Target & Particle size & Reactor type & Heating rate & Operation mode\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{3em}{Bio-oil\\Syngas\\Biochar\\Heat} &
\multirow{4}{3em}{Trucks\\Chips\\Fine particles} &
\multirow{4}{3em}{Fixed bed\\Moving bed\\Fluidized bed} &
\multirow{4}{3em}{Slow\\Fast} &
\multirow{4}{3em}{Batch\\Continuous\\Intermittent}\\
\end{tabular}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FAST SLOW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsection{Fast and slow pyrolysis}
Slow pyrolysis, or conventional carbonization, is the oldest industrial technologies developed by humankind \cite{Harris:1999}.
\end{document}
```

But the output is this:

[image]

Any idea? :)

Comment: try `\raggedbottom` in the preamble

Comment: What's the purpose of `\multirow`? I cannot find one. Please, make a compilable example.

Comment: thanks Herbert, I tried you solution without any success :( always the same output

Comment: thanks egreg, the package is this: \usepackage{multirow} with this should be compilable

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the overprinting is `\multirow{4}{...}`. Its text covers the current and the next three rows. But the next three rows do not exist. At least dummy rows should be provided.

## Five tables

But as far as I can see, the columns are independent from each other. Therefore it is actually not one big table but five separate tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% nicer horizontal lines

\begin{document}
The diversity of feedstocks which can be processed by pyrolysis and the
large number of design variables make it difficult to identify the optimum
pyrolysis technology for a given situation.

\begingroup
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \toprule
    Target \\
    \midrule
    Bio-oil \\ Syngas \\ Biochar \\ Heat \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
  \hspace{.5em plus 1fill}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \toprule
    Particle size \\
    \midrule
    Trucks \\ Chips \\ Fine particles \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \hspace{.5em plus 1fill}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \toprule
    Reactor type \\
    \midrule
    Fixed bed \\ Moving bed \\ Fluidized bed \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \hspace{.5em plus 1fill}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \toprule
    Heating \\ rate \\
    \midrule
    Slow \\ Fast \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \hspace{.5em plus 1fill}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \toprule
    Operation \\ mode \\
    \midrule
    Batch \\ Continuous \\ Intermittent \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \par
\endgroup

\subsection{Fast and slow pyrolysis}
Slow pyrolysis, or conventional carbonization, is the oldest industrial
technologies developed by humankind.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## One table

Here a "one-table" version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
The diversity of feedstocks which can be processed by pyrolysis and the
large number of design variables make it difficult to identify the optimum
pyrolysis technology for a given situation.

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5\tabcolsep}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\kern\tabcolsep\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc}
    \toprule
    Target & Particle size & Reactor type
    & \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} Heating\\rate\end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} Operation\\mode\end{tabular}
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
    Bio-oil & Trucks & Fixed bed & Slow & Batch \\
    Syngas & Chips & Moving bed & Fast & Continuous \\
    Biochar & Fine particles & Fluidized bed & & Intermittent \\
    Heat & & & & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\subsection{Fast and slow pyrolysis}
Slow pyrolysis, or conventional carbonization, is the oldest industrial
technologies developed by humankind.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result one table]

Comment: Whether the OP wants to have one or more than one table is not quite clear from his posting. However, his problems are related to the use of `\multirow`.

Comment: number one man!!! ;) thanks, 5 tables are fine as well :)

Comment: @phx See my updated answer, the table rows, where `\multirow` puts its stuff are missing.